No analog output coming from my headphones on Ubuntu 24.10
My Ubuntu "Sound" control panel is showing the input and output device correctly as "Headphones - USB Audio". It's not muted and the test looks like it is outputting sound. But there's nothing coming out of my headphones, which are plugged into my PC's front panel headphone jack.
I've tried downgrading to pulseaudio from pipewire, with no success. I can't think of anything that might be wrong except that "amixer -c 1" doesn't show an 'Analog out' option. Here's the output:
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Front Center: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Woofer: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Side Left: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
  Side Right: Playback 75 [86%] [-9.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 60 [69%] [-20.25dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 60 [69%] [-20.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 39
  Front Left: Capture 0 [0%] [-17.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 0 [0%] [-17.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 39
  Front Left: Capture 39 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 39 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Analog In',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 39
  Front Left: Capture 23 [59%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 23 [59%] [0.00dB] [on]

"lspci" shows the right audio card:
71:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7e51]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Here is the output from "pactl list sinks":
Sink #66
State: IDLE
Name: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo
Description: USB Audio Analog Stereo
Driver: PipeWire
Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 4294967295
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 45161 /  69% / -9.70 dB,   front-right: 45161 /  69% / -9.70 dB
        balance 0.00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.components = "USB0db0:cd0e"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    alsa.id = "Audio"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:0b:00.0-5, high speed"
    alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
    alsa.name = "USB Audio"
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.sync.id = "00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:0b:00.0-5, high speed"
    api.alsa.card.name = "USB Audio"
    api.alsa.path = "front:1"
    api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
    api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
    audio.channels = "2"
    audio.position = "FL,FR"
    card.profile.device = "9"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.id = "57"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.routes = "2"
    factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
    media.class = "Audio/Sink"
    device.description = "USB Audio"
    node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo"
    node.nick = "USB Audio"
    node.pause-on-idle = "false"
    object.path = "alsa:acp:Audio:9:playback"
    port.group = "playback"
    priority.driver = "1009"
    priority.session = "1009"
    factory.id = "19"
    clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
    client.id = "47"
    node.driver = "true"
    node.loop.name = "data-loop.0"
    library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
    object.id = "66"
    object.serial = "66"
    node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
    api.alsa.period-size = "512"
    api.alsa.period-num = "64"
    api.alsa.headroom = "512"
    api.acp.auto-port = "false"
    api.alsa.card = "1"
    api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.bus-id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0b:00.0-usb-0:5:1.0"
    device.enum.api = "udev"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
    device.name = "alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
    device.nick = "USB Audio"
    device.plugged.usec = "12059944"
    device.product.id = "0xcd0e"
    device.product.name = "USB Audio"
    device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
    device.subsystem = "sound"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:0c.0/0000:0b:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/sound/card1"
    device.vendor.id = "0x0db0"
    device.vendor.name = "Micro Star International"
    device.string = "1"
Ports:
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 4, available)
Active Port: analog-output-headphones
Formats:
    pcm

Sink #70
State: SUSPENDED
Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1
Description: HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
Driver: PipeWire
Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 4294967295
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 0 /   0% / -inf dB,   front-right: 0 /   0% / -inf dB
        balance 0.00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
Properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10de00a4,10438962,00100100"
    alsa.device = "7"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    alsa.id = "NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xde080000 irq 128"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU a4 HDMI/DP"
    alsa.name = "G272QPF E2"
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.sync.id = "00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xde080000 irq 128"
    api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
    api.alsa.path = "hdmi:0,1"
    api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
    api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
    audio.channels = "2"
    audio.position = "FL,FR"
    card.profile.device = "5"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.id = "58"
    device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
    device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
    device.routes = "1"
    factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
    media.class = "Audio/Sink"
    device.description = "HDA NVidia"
    node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1"
    node.nick = "G272QPF E2"
    node.pause-on-idle = "false"
    object.path = "alsa:acp:NVidia:5:playback"
    port.group = "playback"
    priority.driver = "632"
    priority.session = "632"
    factory.id = "19"
    clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
    client.id = "47"
    node.driver = "true"
    node.loop.name = "data-loop.0"
    library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
    object.id = "68"
    object.serial = "70"
    api.acp.auto-port = "false"
    api.alsa.card = "0"
    api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    device.enum.api = "udev"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
    device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
    device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
    device.plugged.usec = "6535450"
    device.product.id = "0x22bb"
    device.subsystem = "sound"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
    device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    device.string = "0"
Ports:
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, availability group: Legacy 2, available)
Active Port: hdmi-output-1
Formats:
    pcm

Here's the output of "pactl list cards":
Card #56
Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_71_00.1
Driver: alsa
Owner Module: n/a
Properties:
    api.acp.auto-port = "false"
    api.alsa.card = "2"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xde788000 irq 130"
    api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
    api.alsa.path = "hw:2"
    api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio2"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:71:00.1"
    device.description = "Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.enum.api = "udev"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
    device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_71_00.1"
    device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
    device.plugged.usec = "6535325"
    device.product.id = "0x1640"
    device.product.name = "Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.subsystem = "sound"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:71:00.1/sound/card2"
    device.vendor.id = "0x1002"
    device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    media.class = "Audio/Device"
    factory.id = "15"
    client.id = "47"
    object.id = "56"
    object.serial = "56"
    object.path = "alsa:acp:Generic_1"
    alsa.card = "2"
    alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xde788000 irq 130"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    alsa.mixer_name = "ATI R6xx HDMI"
    alsa.components = "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100800"
    alsa.id = "Generic_1"
    device.string = "2"
Profiles:
    off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
Active Profile: off
Ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "0"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "1"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "2"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "3"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #57
Name: alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00
Driver: alsa
Owner Module: n/a
Properties:
    api.acp.auto-port = "false"
    api.alsa.card = "1"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:0b:00.0-5, high speed"
    api.alsa.card.name = "USB Audio"
    api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
    api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.bus-id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0b:00.0-usb-0:5:1.0"
    device.description = "USB Audio"
    device.enum.api = "udev"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
    device.name = "alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
    device.nick = "USB Audio"
    device.plugged.usec = "12059944"
    device.product.id = "0xcd0e"
    device.product.name = "USB Audio"
    device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
    device.subsystem = "sound"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:0c.0/0000:0b:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/sound/card1"
    device.vendor.id = "0x0db0"
    device.vendor.name = "Micro Star International"
    media.class = "Audio/Device"
    factory.id = "15"
    client.id = "47"
    object.id = "57"
    object.serial = "57"
    object.path = "alsa:acp:Audio"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:0b:00.0-5, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
    alsa.components = "USB0db0:cd0e"
    alsa.id = "Audio"
    device.string = "1"
Profiles:
    off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
    output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: yes)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: yes)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5555, available: yes)
    output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
    output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
    output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
    output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 365, available: yes)
    output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 355, available: yes)
    output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
    input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 55, available: yes)
    pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 3, priority: 1, available: yes)
Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
Ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "mic"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            card.profile.port = "0"
        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
    analog-input-linein: Line In (type: Line, priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "line"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
            card.profile.port = "1"
        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
    iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
        Properties:
            port.type = "spdif"
            card.profile.port = "2"
        Part of profile(s): input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "speaker"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            card.profile.port = "3"
        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "headphones"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            card.profile.port = "4"
        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
    iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
        Properties:
            port.type = "spdif"
            card.profile.port = "5"
        Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo

Card #58
Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
Driver: alsa
Owner Module: n/a
Properties:
    api.acp.auto-port = "false"
    api.alsa.card = "0"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xde080000 irq 128"
    api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
    api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
    api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
    api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    device.description = "HDA NVidia"
    device.enum.api = "udev"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
    device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
    device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
    device.plugged.usec = "6535450"
    device.product.id = "0x22bb"
    device.subsystem = "sound"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
    device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    media.class = "Audio/Device"
    factory.id = "15"
    client.id = "47"
    object.id = "58"
    object.serial = "58"
    object.path = "alsa:acp:NVidia"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xde080000 irq 128"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU a4 HDMI/DP"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10de00a4,10438962,00100100"
    alsa.id = "NVidia"
    device.string = "0"
Profiles:
    off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: yes)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: yes)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
    pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
Active Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
Ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "0"
            device.product.name = "G272QPF E2
"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "1"
            device.product.name = "G272QPF E2
"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "2"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
        Properties:
            port.type = "hdmi"
            port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            card.profile.port = "3"
        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3


I have had some issues with my sound output and input.
I have found that using 'PulseAudio Volume Control' app from really helps in determining and fixing audio issues.
You can get it as a flatpak if you install 'gnome software' withthe additional flatpak plugin.

Try this; at least this is how I solved it on my 24.10:
Open up alsamixer in your terminal, select your audio device, press F5 to see all channels. There is chance that the Headphones channel may be set to 0 or muted. If so, select it, increase the volume with the arrow up. Press m to mute and unmute.

Nothing is muted. The issue remains unresolved. Thanks anyways.
